# Add Exisiting Domain user to Local Computer with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windowsdomainaccount

I'm trying to automate the desktop file migration of user accounts for some of our legacy users. I have a powershell script that can remove them from whatever domain the may be joined too, then join our current domain. But I want to copy files from the old user account to their new domain account, but how can I add the domain user profile to the local computer without breaking my powershell script and then starting it again.

I've got Admin access to Local Machine, New Domain, and User credentials. Just need something like `Add-User -Credential $USRcred -DomainName $DOMAIN` or something. My users already exist in the new domain, I just need their user profile downloaded/setup on the local machine.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the only way to do that is for the user to log in.

Comment: That seems like a major oversight by Microsoft (not that I'm surprised). I've noticed that I **AM** able to launch programs as another user, like starting a new powershell with a different user's permissions, but that's not helpfully for my project.

Comment: It's not an oversight as Microsoft do support domain migration with [ADMT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(v=ws.10).aspx), they just don't support the labor-intensive manual way you want to do it. ADMT can migrate both [Roaming and Local Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974427(v=ws.10).aspx) for you.

Comment: Also there is `USMT` which has the `/mu` flag that can be used for cross domain migration  `/mu:OldDomain\OldUser:NewDomain\NewUser` on an individual level.

Comment: you can use `runas` from sysinternals or WinRM directly if enabled to remotely execute your script on the local computers

Comment: The `LogonUser` API function will create the user's profile if it does not already exist.  But I'd consider this risky, I'm not certain that the first-time setup will behave entirely correctly if the user profile already exists.  That could cause hard-to-diagnose bugs later on.